# Как поделить коллекцию между потоками поровну?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Есть два списка

```
var proxy = new List<string>(); // 4 прокси
var urls = new List<string>(); // 100 урлов
```

Я использую `Parallel.For` для того чтобы реализовать многопоток. Теперь стоит вопрос в том чтобы каждый прокси делал только 25 запросов (25*4=100). Как я вижу самый лучший вариант поделить список на `urls.Count/proxy.Count`. Однако может быть такое что если коллекция будет больше, то получается что один и тот же поток с одной прокси может несколько раз взять данные из коллекции. Как быть?

```
  Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, urls.Count, urls.Count / proxy.Count), new ParallelOptions {
     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
    }, range => {
     for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++) {
      ....
     }
    });
```

Comment: А давайте вы опишете задачу целиком. Дело в том, что распараллеливание предназначено для CPU-bound задач, в то время как в описании наличествуют прокси и урлы, что может означать IO-bound задачи.

Comment: А для чего вам именно одинаковое количество задач? Если вы доверитесь автоматическому распределению, оно по идее поделит не на равное количество, а так, чтобы уменьшить общее время работы — разве это не то, что вам нужно? Ну и да, непонятно, почему вы просто не пользуетесь async/await и TPL, раз ваше узкое место — не процессор.

Comment: В C# это делается однострочником: `range.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4).ForAll(...)`. Для чего вам нужно делить коллекцию именно поровну?

Answer (score -1):

Как уже выше написали, для вашей задачи использовать параллельный вариант циклов не самая лучшая идея.

У меня недавно была похожая задача, когда надо было сделать 110000 запросов и потом распарсить результаты. Последовательная обработка заняла 16 часов, в то же время пять потоков сделали её за ~2 часа 10 минут.

Я бы посоветовал создать несколько Task'ов(Я делал 'Количество ядер процессора' - 1), делить коллекцию по количеству потоков и передавать всё в делегат Task'а в качестве параметра.

Код примерно такой:

```
await Task.Run(() => StartHtmlReadingAsync(lines, maxThreads));
```

...

```
private async Task<int> StartHtmlReadingAsync(string[] lines, int maxThreads)
{
   string[][] splittedArray = lines.SplitTo(maxThreads - 1);
   Task<int>[] listOfActions = new Task<int>[splittedKnArray.Length];
   for(int index = 0; index < splittedKnArray.Length; index++)
   {
       int idx = index;
       listOfActions[idx] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFromSiteAsync(splittedKnArray[idx])).Unwrap();
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(listOfActions)
}
```

...

```
private async Task<int> ReadFromSiteAsync(string[] objs)
{
...
}
```

Comment: И вы тоже свою задачу не целиком описали. 16 часов шла нагрузка на процессор или запросы куда-то? Если боттлнек был в ожидании ответов, то задач можно создавать намного больше, чем имеется ядер.

Comment: 16 часов шли запросы к серверу и ожидание ответа. Да, можно и больше, но профит был уже не такой большой.